# Can´t use copied symfony2 config

Tags: php, symfony

I copied my config_test.yml and parameters_test.yml to "config_localtest.yml" and "parameters_localtest.yml". 
After that i change the includes in config_localtest.yml from parameters_test.yml to parameters_localtest.yml. Beside that little change the files are identical.

When i´m doing a

```
bin/console cache:clear --env="test"
```

Everything is working like before. If i would do the same for the new config

```
bin/console cache:clear --env="localtest"
```

an error is thrown:

```
  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "web_profiler" (in /var/www/.../htdocs/app/config/config_localtest.yml). Looked for namespace "web_profiler", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "and all other ..."
```

I already deleted cache manually - no other result. 
What else should it try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony can't find find Bundle for you config so
I think you are missing localtest inside AppKernel ( app/AppKernel.php )
it has a line that looks like this

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
}
```

so add localtest inside `['dev', 'test']` and it should work fine

Comment: Shame on me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the configure for web_profiler:

```
# config_localtest.yml
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
```

Add the above 3 lines of config in your `config_localtest.yml` file.